# What does Ok! indicate

Tags: word-usage, exclamations

Some one had a query and gave him the answer in chat. He replied 'Ok!'. What does ! after 'Ok' mean? Does it indicate sarcasm?

Comment: while most people don't use sarcasm marks an exclamation mark can mean that. In all likelihood they were just enthusiastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to read sarcasm into it just by the exclamation mark. As mentioned in the member's comment above, the **(!)** most commonly denotes enthusiasm. Exclamation marks are not routine indicators of sarcasm unless a large number of them are used together in an inappropriate situation. Sarcasm is mainly expressed through word choice and usage, and not usually with punctuation alone.

Examples:

A: we could meet up at the coffee shop at 5 pm.

**B: Ok! (Enthusiasm)**

C: I strongly condemn your action and plan to lodge a complaint.

**D: OMG! I am quaking in my boots! (Sarcasm)**

However,  the whole chat taken in context might tell you whether sarcasm was implied or not.

Comment: I work in IT, and a number of my [mostly younger] users seem to use a  '!' where I'd use a full stop/period.  If they want to emphasize a sentence, they use three or four exclamation marks.  It's nearly as irritating as WRITING EVERYTHING IN CAPITALS!!!

Comment: Excessive use of exclamation marks is frowned upon by grammar gurus. But my young sister N,  who is very fond of the **(!)** -- not to the extent of using multiple !!!!!, but particular to use the single **(!)** like a full stop -- says that text message or email sentences appear **dull, flat and lifeless** with full stops instead of exclamations! She is 26 now and that may explain the partiality to the humble **(!)**

Comment: just to clarify, does N use "!" or "(!)" at then end of most sentences?  If the latter, she sounds a very sarcastic sort of person(!)

Comment: Of course she uses **!** without the brackets!  Our trouble here is that it's much easier to actually use grammatical constructions and punctuation marks than to **refer to** them in discussion -- so much so that a whole new orthography for linguistic discussion based on quotation marks, brackets and selective boldface may be taking shape through EL & U!

Comment: Well put, @English Student.